# Futuro semplice oppure Congiuntivo presente

Tags: grammar, tenses

Sto guardando questo [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewQpb4HwsSE&list=PLY27cJTUBR0tGFLrLcR9VDKfNyNwFnY7B&index=21). Il titolo della lezione è:

> Che cosa farò quando sarò guarita?

In questo titolo è usato il verbo `essere`. In spagnolo useremmo il congiuntivo presente:

> Che cosa farò quando sia guarita?

Vorrei sapere quale tempo si deve usare e perché.

Comment: Ho trovato la risposta su questo [sito](http://www.curso-de-italiano.de/gramatica/capitulo11/11_3_4_formacion_futuro_2.htm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In italiano si usa il futuro indicativo:

> Che cosa farò quando sarò guarita?

Non c'è un motivo preciso, probabilmente perché il parlante qui è sicuro di guarire, mentre il congiuntivo è il modo della possibilità. Per esempio qui si usa il congiuntivo:

> Che cosa farò domani ammettendo che io sia guarita?

Comment: +1, e aggiungo: "quando" implica proprio che c'è la certezza di guarire, non la possibilità.